# Set with expiration not working inside running Python script

Tags: python, process, queue, set

I have this class called DecayingSet which is a deque with expiration

```
class DecayingSet:
    def __init__(self, timeout): # timeout in seconds
        from collections import deque
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.d = deque()
        self.present = set()

    def add(self, thing):
       # Return True if `thing` not already in set,
       # else return False.
        result = thing not in self.present
        if result:
          self.present.add(thing)
          self.d.append((time(), thing))
        self.clean()
        return result

    def clean(self):
       # forget stuff added >= `timeout` seconds ago
       now = time()
       d = self.d
       while d and now - d[0][0] >= self.timeout:
            _, thing = d.popleft()
            self.present.remove(thing)
```

I'm trying to use it inside a running script, that connects to a streaming api.
The streaming api is returning urls that I am trying to put inside the deque to limit them from entering the next step of the program.

```
    class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
         def on_status(self, status, include_entities=True):
             longUrl = status.entities['urls'][0]['expanded_url']

             limit = DecayingSet(86400)
             l = limit.add(longUrl)
             print l
             if l == False:
              pass
             else:
              r = requests.get("http://api.some.url/show?url=%s"% longUrl)
```

When i use this class in an interpreter, everything is good.
But when the script is running, and I repeatedly send in the same url, l returns True every time indicating that the url is not inside the set, when is supposed to be. What gives?

Comment: I think the indentation is screwed up, but it *looks like* you're creating a brand new `limit` object every time `on_status()` is called.  Then of course it would always return `True`:  you'd always be starting with an empty `limit`.

Comment: Is this the actual code? There's weird indentation above that I'd think Python would choke on.

Comment: yes my indentation in the qs is off, its fine in the code. and YES!! i just saw in the interpreter the var assignment is the culprit. How would I use the same obj?

Comment: You could, for example, create the `limit` object at the module level.  I can't be more specific without having *all* your code to stare at.  But this should be dead easy ;-)

Comment: as always this is something simple that i'm missing out on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my comment ;-)  I think the indentation is screwed up, but it looks like you're creating a brand new `limit` object every time `on_status()` is called. Then of course it would always return `True`:  you'd always be starting with an empty `limit`.

Regardless, change this:

```
     l = limit.add(longUrl)
     print l
     if l == False:
        pass
     else:
        r = requests.get("http://api.some.url/show?url=%s"% longUrl)
```

to this:

```
     if limit.add(longUrl):
        r = requests.get("http://api.some.url/show?url=%s"% longUrl)
```

Much easier to follow.  It's *usually* the case that when you're comparing something to a literal `True` or `False`, the code can be made more readable.

### Edit

> i just saw in the interpreter the var assignment is the culprit.
>   How would I use the same obj?

You could, for example, create the `limit` object at the module level.  Cut and paste ;-)

Comment: but where does the comparison come in, how does the code know what to do when true or false returns? which is the default behavior

Comment: Heh - read the docs for the `if` statement.  `if <expression>: <block>` executes the `<block>` if and only if `<expression>` evaluates to a "truthy" value.  There's nothing *more* truthy than `True`, and nothing less truthy than `False` ;-)  Comparison has nothing to do with it!  Comparisons are just one way of writing a "truthy" expression.

Comment: THANK YOU! @Tim-Peters. True is the default, it's the TRUTH!! that's what if is looking for the TRUTH. create the limit obj elsewhere. and i moved the limit = DecayingSet(86400) outside of the class/function! now it works as advertised

Comment: put that in the answer and ill accept it..." create the limit object elsewhere "

Comment: I've discovered a flaw in my design. If i restart the script a new obj instance gets created therefore allowing duplicates to enter in. Anyway to make the set persistent across script resets. Memcache might be the way to go or is there a way to save the set to disk then keep checking on that object even during restarts. gonna research pickle, shelve, and shove... am I on the right track?